# How do I change a str to and int and vise versa without using any built in python functions?

Tags: python, string, int

The function assumes that in both cases the input is acceptable (ie.) when doing str to int assume that the str contains an actual int and vise versa always works anyway

The function must also not use the easy to use built in python functions such as int() or str(). Can only use basic coding along with def headers such as (for i in rang() and conditionals and what not.) Pls Help. :)

Comment: It's good that you tagged this as homework, but you still need to show what you've tried or ask a specific question about what you can't figure out.

Comment: `range()` is a builtin function, so you can't use it? or is there a bunch of exceptions?

Comment: @gnibbler: `range()` (or at least `xrange()`) is something that, in my opinion, because it _does_ belong to the basic coding. Without it you wouldn't probably have the ability to do basic `for` loop known from other languages (such as `for(var i=0; i<10; i++)` for example). Or you would need to list all the values of `i` like `for i in [0,1,2,3,4]` instead of `for i in xrange(5)`.

Comment: I despise these kind of questions.  If you are using a high-level language, then use a high-level language!

Comment: @Tadeck, it's actually pretty easy to replace that with a while loop

Comment: @gnibbler: You are right, I forgot about that. That question goes on the wrong track, because the goal here is to avoid best practices ;)

Comment: http://writemycode.net - may have an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

```
def str2int(s):
    i = 0
    chr2digit = {`j`:j for j in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)}
    for c in s:
        i = i*10 + chr2digit[c]
    return i


def int2str(i):  # rather easy in Python2
    return `i`

def int2str(i):  # works in Python2 and Python3
    return "%s"%i
```

Comment: @ch3ka How is this worse than ten `if`s?

Comment: @ch3ka, using a dictionary like this (as a mapping) is pretty normal when dealing with arbitrary mappings. Not allowed to use `ord()` so it's a good fit here. Normally I wouldn't inline the dict, but this is just play code, so what's the problem?

Comment: @agf it is not, both should burn in hell.

Comment: @ch3ka: given the ridiculous restrictions, I don't think *any* nice solution exists. There's only one (obvious) way to do a thing in Python, and when you arbitrarily disallow the obvious way you're left with alternatives like this.

Comment: I upvoted the edited form. Seems a good tradeoff between restrictions and not dumbassery.

Answer (score 1):

It may be ugly, but it works. See this function:

```py
>>> def strint(val):
    digits = '0123456789'
    try:
        # Trying to treat it as a string-to-int conversion
        result = 0
        for l in val:
            result = result * 10 + digits.index(l)
    except (TypeError,):
        # There was a type error - we have int instead of string
        result = ''
        while val:
            digit = val % 10
            result = digits[digit] + result
            val = val // 10
        else:
            if not val and not result:
                result = '0'
    return result

>>> strint('123')
123
>>> strint(123)
'123'
>>> strint('0')
0
>>> strint(0)
'0'
```

Comment: I didn't think you are allowed to use `digits.index`

Comment: @gnibbler: If `digits.index` is indeed not allowed, I would probably use something like `[i for i in xrange(len(digits)) if digits[i] == l][0]`. And I believe `xrange` / `range` is allowed, because without it you wouldn't have such a basic solution like `for` loop known from other languages. If `len` is also not allowed, I would use just `10` instead of `len(digits)`, because the number of decimal digits is rather constant ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is only for the `int` replacement and doesn't handle everything, but it is homework so I'll let you do the rest.  It could be made a little simpler if you use `ord`.

```
def myint(s):
   x = 0
   for ch in s:
      if ch == '0': x = x * 10 + 0
      if ch == '1': x = x * 10 + 1
      if ch == '2': x = x * 10 + 2
      if ch == '3': x = x * 10 + 3
      if ch == '4': x = x * 10 + 4
      if ch == '5': x = x * 10 + 5
      if ch == '6': x = x * 10 + 6
      if ch == '7': x = x * 10 + 7
      if ch == '8': x = x * 10 + 8
      if ch == '9': x = x * 10 + 9
   return x
```

Comment: even the ugly function above is less ugly than this.

Comment: @ch3ka, _above_ is not a very useful concept when the ordering of the answers keeps changing :)

Comment: A disadvantage of the chain of if's is that you are doing 10 comparisons for each digit

Comment: @gnibbler you are of course right, this is my first day here. I meant Tadecks solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach you may consider:

```
x = "1"
print type(x)
<type 'str'>
import string
if x in string.digits:
    # Now you know that x is a number
    print x
```

You can do the same with [string.ascii_letters](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) too. Not a complete answer, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Unless `x` is `10`, which is not `in string.digits`.

Comment: Both x[0] and x[1] would be however.